# Finding football foul that results in succesful shot on target

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains a foul made by a player which eventually leads to a shot on target.
What I want to do is create a new column that puts either TRUE/FALSE, where TRUE is set, if the foul of a player leads to a successful shot on target by the opponent (thus the opposite team of the player that made a foul). This should happen within 120 seconds (from the time_seconds column). Rows 15 and 16 provide an example:

In row 15 the away-team (i.e. home_team == FALSE) commits a foul,
where in row 16, the home-team (i.e. home_team == TRUE) successfully shoots on target.
The timedifference is `time_seconds[16] - time_seconds[15]`, which is approximately 99 seconds.

If this occurs, the new column should put TRUE in row 15.

```
df1 <- structure(list(game_id = c(303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 
303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 
303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 
303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 
303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 
303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 
303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 
303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 
303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L), period_id = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), time_seconds = c(37.89, 
84.336, 180.625, 362.881, 550.039, 704.435, 834.098, 854.326, 
903.619, 1019.792, 1295.223, 1334.372, 1535.632, 1753.75, 1879.466, 
1978.405, 2066.09, 2130.795, 2238.76, 2328.484, 2463.017, 2559.583, 
2652.39, 2793.922, 2835.15, 2873.929, 125.536, 208.099, 537.49, 
706.794, 729.908, 748.267, 801.87, 903.612, 908.616, 1199.159, 
1203.156, 1254.885, 1344.534, 1410.775, 1449.815, 1559.749, 1608.552, 
1622.401, 1706.33, 1707.425, 1790.318, 1836.601, 1863.396, 1911.467, 
2065.581, 2184.689, 2235.202, 2407.699, 2570.467, 2676.898, 2720.759, 
2884.097), home_team = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), player_name = c("Frenkie de Jong", "Jorge Molina Vidal", 
"Marc Cucurella Saseta", "Djené Dakonam Ortega", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", 
"Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini", "Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini", 
"Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Allan Romeo Nyom", "Oghenekaro Etebo", 
"Jorge Molina Vidal", "Allan Romeo Nyom", "Marc Cucurella Saseta", 
"Allan Romeo Nyom", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Antoine Griezmann", 
"Jorge Molina Vidal", "Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo", 
"Anssumane Fati", "Sergi Roberto Carnicer", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", 
"Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Samuel Yves Umtiti", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", 
"Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", "Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini", 
"Oghenekaro Etebo", "Samuel Yves Umtiti", "Gerard Piqué Bernabéu", 
"Anssumane Fati", "Ángel Luis Rodríguez Díaz", "Djené Dakonam Ortega", 
"Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini", "Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi", 
"Djené Dakonam Ortega", "Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo", 
"Sergio Busquets i Burgos", "Ángel Luis Rodríguez Díaz", "Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", 
"Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa", "Anssumane Fati", "Sergio Busquets i Burgos", 
"Ángel Luis Rodríguez Díaz", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Anssumane Fati", 
"Antoine Griezmann", "Frenkie de Jong", "Robert Kenedy Nunes do Nascimento", 
"Amath Ndiaye", "Antoine Griezmann", "Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Héctor Junior Firpo Adames", 
"Jaime Mata Arnaiz", "Allan Romeo Nyom", "Robert Kenedy Nunes do Nascimento", 
"Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini", "Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi", 
"Ángel Luis Rodríguez Díaz"), type_name = c("foul", "foul", "foul", 
"foul", "foul", "shot", "shot", "foul", "foul", "foul", "shot", 
"foul", "shot", "foul", "foul", "shot", "foul", "foul", "foul", 
"shot", "foul", "foul", "foul", "foul", "foul", "shot", "foul", 
"foul", "foul", "foul", "foul", "foul", "shot", "foul", "foul", 
"foul", "foul", "shot", "foul", "foul", "shot", "foul", "shot", 
"foul", "shot", "shot", "foul", "foul", "foul", "shot", "shot", 
"foul", "foul", "foul", "foul", "shot", "foul", "foul"), result_name = c("success", 
"success", "success", "success", "success", "fail", "fail", "success", 
"success", "success", "fail", "success", "fail", "success", "success", 
"success", "success", "success", "success", "success", "success", 
"success", "success", "success", "success", "fail", "success", 
"yellow_card", "success", "success", "success", "success", "fail", 
"success", "success", "success", "success", "success", "success", 
"success", "fail", "success", "fail", "yellow_card", "fail", 
"fail", "success", "success", "success", "fail", "fail", "yellow_card", 
"success", "success", "yellow_card", "fail", "success", "success"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -58L))

# Output
   game_id period_id time_seconds home_team                            player_name type_name result_name
1   303377         1       37.890      TRUE                        Frenkie de Jong      foul     success
2   303377         1       84.336     FALSE                     Jorge Molina Vidal      foul     success
3   303377         1      180.625     FALSE                  Marc Cucurella Saseta      foul     success
4   303377         1      362.881     FALSE                   Djené Dakonam Ortega      foul     success
5   303377         1      550.039     FALSE            Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      foul     success
6   303377         1      704.435      TRUE         Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini      shot        fail
7   303377         1      834.098      TRUE         Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini      shot        fail
8   303377         1      854.326     FALSE                      Jaime Mata Arnaiz      foul     success
9   303377         1      903.619     FALSE                       Allan Romeo Nyom      foul     success
10  303377         1     1019.792     FALSE                       Oghenekaro Etebo      foul     success
11  303377         1     1295.223     FALSE                     Jorge Molina Vidal      shot        fail
12  303377         1     1334.372     FALSE                       Allan Romeo Nyom      foul     success
13  303377         1     1535.632     FALSE                  Marc Cucurella Saseta      shot        fail
14  303377         1     1753.750     FALSE                       Allan Romeo Nyom      foul     success
15  303377         1     1879.466     FALSE                      Jaime Mata Arnaiz      foul     success
16  303377         1     1978.405      TRUE                      Antoine Griezmann      shot     success
17  303377         1     2066.090     FALSE                     Jorge Molina Vidal      foul     success
18  303377         1     2130.795      TRUE Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo      foul     success
19  303377         1     2238.760      TRUE                         Anssumane Fati      foul     success
20  303377         1     2328.484      TRUE                 Sergi Roberto Carnicer      shot     success
21  303377         1     2463.017     FALSE            Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      foul     success
22  303377         1     2559.583     FALSE                      Jaime Mata Arnaiz      foul     success
23  303377         1     2652.390      TRUE                     Samuel Yves Umtiti      foul     success
24  303377         1     2793.922     FALSE            Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      foul     success
25  303377         1     2835.150     FALSE            Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      foul     success
26  303377         1     2873.929      TRUE         Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini      shot        fail
27  303377         2      125.536     FALSE                       Oghenekaro Etebo      foul     success
28  303377         2      208.099      TRUE                     Samuel Yves Umtiti      foul yellow_card
29  303377         2      537.490      TRUE                  Gerard Piqué Bernabéu      foul     success
30  303377         2      706.794      TRUE                         Anssumane Fati      foul     success
31  303377         2      729.908     FALSE              Ángel Luis Rodríguez Díaz      foul     success
32  303377         2      748.267     FALSE                   Djené Dakonam Ortega      foul     success
33  303377         2      801.870      TRUE         Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini      shot        fail
34  303377         2      903.612     FALSE            Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi      foul     success
35  303377         2      908.616     FALSE                   Djené Dakonam Ortega      foul     success
36  303377         2     1199.159      TRUE Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo      foul     success
37  303377         2     1203.156      TRUE               Sergio Busquets i Burgos      foul     success
38  303377         2     1254.885     FALSE              Ángel Luis Rodríguez Díaz      shot     success
39  303377         2     1344.534     FALSE            Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      foul     success
40  303377         2     1410.775     FALSE            Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      foul     success
41  303377         2     1449.815      TRUE                         Anssumane Fati      shot        fail
42  303377         2     1559.749      TRUE               Sergio Busquets i Burgos      foul     success
43  303377         2     1608.552     FALSE              Ángel Luis Rodríguez Díaz      shot        fail
44  303377         2     1622.401     FALSE                      Jaime Mata Arnaiz      foul yellow_card
45  303377         2     1706.330      TRUE                         Anssumane Fati      shot        fail
46  303377         2     1707.425      TRUE                      Antoine Griezmann      shot        fail
47  303377         2     1790.318      TRUE                        Frenkie de Jong      foul     success
48  303377         2     1836.601     FALSE      Robert Kenedy Nunes do Nascimento      foul     success
49  303377         2     1863.396     FALSE                           Amath Ndiaye      foul     success
50  303377         2     1911.467      TRUE                      Antoine Griezmann      shot        fail
51  303377         2     2065.581     FALSE                      Jaime Mata Arnaiz      shot        fail
52  303377         2     2184.689      TRUE             Héctor Junior Firpo Adames      foul yellow_card
53  303377         2     2235.202     FALSE                      Jaime Mata Arnaiz      foul     success
54  303377         2     2407.699     FALSE                       Allan Romeo Nyom      foul     success
55  303377         2     2570.467     FALSE      Robert Kenedy Nunes do Nascimento      foul yellow_card
56  303377         2     2676.898      TRUE         Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini      shot        fail
57  303377         2     2720.759     FALSE            Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi      foul     success
58  303377         2     2884.097     FALSE              Ángel Luis Rodríguez Díaz      foul     success
```

The new dataframe should be like this (only 2 TRUE cases for this small example):

```
   game_id period_id time_seconds home_team                            player_name type_name result_name
1   303377         1       37.890      TRUE                        Frenkie de Jong      foul     success
2   303377         1       84.336     FALSE                     Jorge Molina Vidal      foul     success
3   303377         1      180.625     FALSE                  Marc Cucurella Saseta      foul     success
4   303377         1      362.881     FALSE                   Djené Dakonam Ortega      foul     success
5   303377         1      550.039     FALSE            Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      foul     success
6   303377         1      704.435      TRUE         Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini      shot        fail
7   303377         1      834.098      TRUE         Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini      shot        fail
8   303377         1      854.326     FALSE                      Jaime Mata Arnaiz      foul     success
9   303377         1      903.619     FALSE                       Allan Romeo Nyom      foul     success
10  303377         1     1019.792     FALSE                       Oghenekaro Etebo      foul     success
11  303377         1     1295.223     FALSE                     Jorge Molina Vidal      shot        fail
12  303377         1     1334.372     FALSE                       Allan Romeo Nyom      foul     success
13  303377         1     1535.632     FALSE                  Marc Cucurella Saseta      shot        fail
14  303377         1     1753.750     FALSE                       Allan Romeo Nyom      foul     success
15  303377         1     1879.466     FALSE                      Jaime Mata Arnaiz      foul     success
16  303377         1     1978.405      TRUE                      Antoine Griezmann      shot     success
17  303377         1     2066.090     FALSE                     Jorge Molina Vidal      foul     success
18  303377         1     2130.795      TRUE Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo      foul     success
19  303377         1     2238.760      TRUE                         Anssumane Fati      foul     success
20  303377         1     2328.484      TRUE                 Sergi Roberto Carnicer      shot     success
21  303377         1     2463.017     FALSE            Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      foul     success
22  303377         1     2559.583     FALSE                      Jaime Mata Arnaiz      foul     success
23  303377         1     2652.390      TRUE                     Samuel Yves Umtiti      foul     success
24  303377         1     2793.922     FALSE            Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      foul     success
25  303377         1     2835.150     FALSE            Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      foul     success
26  303377         1     2873.929      TRUE         Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini      shot        fail
27  303377         2      125.536     FALSE                       Oghenekaro Etebo      foul     success
28  303377         2      208.099      TRUE                     Samuel Yves Umtiti      foul yellow_card
29  303377         2      537.490      TRUE                  Gerard Piqué Bernabéu      foul     success
30  303377         2      706.794      TRUE                         Anssumane Fati      foul     success
31  303377         2      729.908     FALSE              Ángel Luis Rodríguez Díaz      foul     success
32  303377         2      748.267     FALSE                   Djené Dakonam Ortega      foul     success
33  303377         2      801.870      TRUE         Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini      shot        fail
34  303377         2      903.612     FALSE            Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi      foul     success
35  303377         2      908.616     FALSE                   Djené Dakonam Ortega      foul     success
36  303377         2     1199.159      TRUE Arthur Henrique Ramos de Oliveira Melo      foul     success
37  303377         2     1203.156      TRUE               Sergio Busquets i Burgos      foul     success
38  303377         2     1254.885     FALSE              Ángel Luis Rodríguez Díaz      shot     success
39  303377         2     1344.534     FALSE            Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      foul     success
40  303377         2     1410.775     FALSE            Mauro Wilney Arambarri Rosa      foul     success
41  303377         2     1449.815      TRUE                         Anssumane Fati      shot        fail
42  303377         2     1559.749      TRUE               Sergio Busquets i Burgos      foul     success
43  303377         2     1608.552     FALSE              Ángel Luis Rodríguez Díaz      shot        fail
44  303377         2     1622.401     FALSE                      Jaime Mata Arnaiz      foul yellow_card
45  303377         2     1706.330      TRUE                         Anssumane Fati      shot        fail
46  303377         2     1707.425      TRUE                      Antoine Griezmann      shot        fail
47  303377         2     1790.318      TRUE                        Frenkie de Jong      foul     success
48  303377         2     1836.601     FALSE      Robert Kenedy Nunes do Nascimento      foul     success
49  303377         2     1863.396     FALSE                           Amath Ndiaye      foul     success
50  303377         2     1911.467      TRUE                      Antoine Griezmann      shot        fail
51  303377         2     2065.581     FALSE                      Jaime Mata Arnaiz      shot        fail
52  303377         2     2184.689      TRUE             Héctor Junior Firpo Adames      foul yellow_card
53  303377         2     2235.202     FALSE                      Jaime Mata Arnaiz      foul     success
54  303377         2     2407.699     FALSE                       Allan Romeo Nyom      foul     success
55  303377         2     2570.467     FALSE      Robert Kenedy Nunes do Nascimento      foul yellow_card
56  303377         2     2676.898      TRUE         Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini      shot        fail
57  303377         2     2720.759     FALSE            Xabier Etxeita Gorritxategi      foul     success
58  303377         2     2884.097     FALSE              Ángel Luis Rodríguez Díaz      foul     success
   foul_goal_concede
1              FALSE
2              FALSE
3              FALSE
4              FALSE
5              FALSE
6              FALSE
7              FALSE
8              FALSE
9              FALSE
10             FALSE
11             FALSE
12             FALSE
13             FALSE
14             FALSE
15             TRUE
16             FALSE
17             FALSE
18             FALSE
19             FALSE
20             FALSE
21             FALSE
22             FALSE
23             FALSE
24             FALSE
25             FALSE
26             FALSE
27             FALSE
28             FALSE
29             FALSE
30             FALSE
31             FALSE
32             FALSE
33             FALSE
34             FALSE
35             FALSE
36             FALSE
37             TRUE
38             FALSE
39             FALSE
40             FALSE
41             FALSE
42             FALSE
43             FALSE
44             FALSE
45             FALSE
46             FALSE
47             FALSE
48             FALSE
49             FALSE
50             FALSE
51             FALSE
52             FALSE
53             FALSE
54             FALSE
55             FALSE
56             FALSE
57             FALSE
58             FALSE
```

I hope this is clear enough ;')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` approach. Probably not the fastest, but it will get the job done.

```
library(data.table)
# Make it a data.table
setDT(df1)
# Create an id-column
df1[, rowid := .I]
# Set id column as key
setkey(df1, rowid)
# Create temp data.table with all succesfull shots
dt.shot.success <- df1[type_name == "shot" & result_name == "success", ]
# perform join on all fouls
df1[df1[type_name == "foul", ], foul_to_goal_within_120 := {
  temp <- dt.shot.success[!home_team == i.home_team & 
                            game_id == i.game_id &
                            period_id == i.period_id &
                            time_seconds %between% c(i.time_seconds, i.time_seconds + 120), ]
  list(nrow(temp) > 0)
}, by = .EACHI][]

#fouls on row 15, 36 and 37 lead to a successfull shot for the other team within 120 seconds
```